# how can refresh list when click button in item listview

Tags: android, listview, refresh

i have recyclerview and button on the all item of list. when i click the button in my adapter item deleted and i want refresh recycler and show new data.

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final LietnerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    lietner = lietners.get(position);
    holder.txt_en.setText(lietner.getText_en());
    holder.txt_pe.setText(lietner.getText_pe());
    holder.time.setText(lietner.getTime());
    holder.data.setText(HelperCalendar.g2j(lietner.getTime_create()));
    holder.next_level.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
      G.databaseOpenHelper.goToNextLevel(lietners.get(position).getId());

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: call *notifyDataSetChanged()*

Answer (score 2):

For re-initializing the recycler view and get callback on *onBindViewHolder*

simple call *notifyDataSetChanged();*

```
       @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LietnerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        lietner = lietners.get(position);

        holder.next_level.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // delete the item, or change the data.
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i do this and it work for me!

```
@Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final LietnerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    lietner = lietners.get(position);
    holder.txt_en.setText(lietner.getText_en());
    holder.txt_pe.setText(lietner.getText_pe());
    holder.time.setText(lietner.getTime());
    holder.data.setText(HelperCalendar.g2j(lietner.getTime_create()));
    holder.next_level.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        G.databaseOpenHelper.goToNextLevel(lietners.get(position).getId());
        lietners.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I see you like answering your own questions instead of giving credit to other answers. This guy gave you the exact same answer then this one.